# border-style:none; set on my anchor tags but border shows up when I click on a link - why?

Tags: html, css

The border style css is given on my anchor tags but border shows up when I click on a link - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { outline: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this style.

```
a { text-decoration: none; outline:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for all the anchor tags in html

a {outline:none;}

a {outline:none!important;}

And you can use for a particular class or id

.demo a {outline:none;}

Add !important if not working